# Change usd to euro in magento

Tags: php, magento

I want to change the currency in magento from usd to euro. When i try to change from the admin panel (System->Configuration->currency) the default currency to euro the following error shows: Selected default display currency is not available in allowed currencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
System->Configuration->General->Currency setup->Currency options tab,
```

euro should be selected in

```
Allowed Currencies multiselect.
```

P.S. Use CTRL key to select multiple values.